# How to get Microsoft Exchange email addresses other than the primary SMTP address using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, exchange-server

I'm attempting to pull contact information from an `Outlook.ExchangeUser` object using VBA in Excel. However, so far I've only been able to get the primary SMTP address for each user - but I would like to get EVERY email address linked to each account if possible. We recently rebranded and got a new domain, and so the new email address has become our primary email address - but I would also like to extract all of the old addresses alongside this, as these are still usable (and some have more than one older email address).

A colleague gave me the following code to work with:

```
Sub GetAllGALMembers()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olGAL As Outlook.AddressList
Dim olEntry As Outlook.AddressEntries
Dim olMember As Outlook.AddressEntry

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olGAL = olNS.GetGlobalAddressList()

'Set Up Excel
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

'set the workbook:
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
'set the worksheet where you want to post Outlook data:
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

'clear all current entries
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents

'set and format headings in the worksheet:
ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "First Name"
ws.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Last Name"
ws.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Email"
ws.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Title"
ws.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Department"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ws.Range("A1:E1")

.Font.Bold = True
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

End With

Set olEntry = olGAL.AddressEntries
On Error Resume Next
'first row of entries
j = 2

' loop through dist list and extract members
For i = 1 To olEntry.Count

Set olMember = olEntry.Item(i)

If olMember.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeUserAddressEntry Then
'add to worksheet
ws.Cells(j, 1).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.LastName
ws.Cells(j, 2).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.FirstName
ws.Cells(j, 3).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
ws.Cells(j, 4).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.JobTitle
ws.Cells(j, 5).Value = olMember.GetExchangeUser.Department
j = j + 1
End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'determine last data row, basis column B (contains Last Name):
lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'format worksheet data area:
ws.Range("A2:E" & lastRow).Sort Key1:=ws.Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending
ws.Range("A2:E" & lastRow).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
ws.Columns("A:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit

wb.Save

'quit the Outlook application:
applOutlook.Quit

'clear the variables:
Set olApp = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olGAL = Nothing

End Sub
```

This is working really well, however all I can get is a single email address for each user, through the `.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress` property.

I've checked the [Outlook Object Model Reference for the ExchangeUser Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff870767(v=office.14).aspx) but this only includes the `ExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress` Property, and no other relevant properties.

Is there a way to pull every email address associated to a user? Or am I limited to only getting the primary address and no others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting indeed. I'll have to look into macros in Excel for this when I get back to my work station. Interesting. As a caveat, there is a way in the Exchange Management Shell, which I assume is installed since you can use Exchange macros in Excel. I could be wrong in that assumption, but here it goes anyway:

```
Get-MailboxDatabase -IncludePreExchange2013 | Get-mailbox | % { Get-ADUser $_.Alias -Properties Surname, GivenName, @{N="EmailAddresses"; E={$_.ProxyAddresses | % {[string]::join("|",$_)}}}, Title, Department} | Export-csv <location you want to save it> -NoTypeInformation
```

If you have all the users you want to check already in a CSV file, you could also do the following:

```
Import-csv <location of your source csv file> | Get-ADUser $_.Username -Properties Surname, GivenName, @{N="EmailAddresses"; E={$_.ProxyAddresses | % {[string]::join("|",$_)}}}, Title, Department} | Export-csv <location you want to save it> -NoTypeInformation
```

Just make sure you have a column called "Username" in your CSV file that has the accounts' username that you are trying to look up.

Comment: That will not work if the OP connects to a hosted (Office 365) mailbox, or in case of on-prem server and the user having no right to access using Exchange Management Shell (which will happen in 99.9% of all cases).

Comment: I did indeed assume the OP has access to use EMS. I had a feeling that a normal user probably isn't editing VBA code. As far as O365 goes, I'm sure there's a Powershell way to do it also. I've not looked into it too much, but I'd put money on it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to read the `PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES` MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101F`) using `AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. It is a multivalued property, so you will get back an array of strings.

You can see the property and its values in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click IMAPISession | QueryIdentity button or IAddrBook, and then drill down to a GAL entry in question).